# For loop to iterate over data frame columns and return column names plus calculations

Tags: r

```
v1 = c(5, "", 6)
v2 = c(4, 3, 7)
df1 = data.frame(v1,v2)
```

I'm trying to use a for loop to iterate over a data frame and print the column name, the number of empty values, plus other calculations.

I'm struggling to iterate over the columns in a way I could get both the column name and do calculations. I'm looking for an answer in the form of:

```
for (i in **SOME MECHANISM TO SELECT THE COLUMNS AS PER ABOVE**) {
  **print the column name here**
  print(sum(is.na(i)))
}
```

The returned result with the dataset provided would be

v1

1

v2

0

Comment: Note that `v1 = c(5, "", 6)` will be coerced into a character vector by the `""`.  Use `v1 <- c(5, NA, 6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are searching for ?

```
v1 = c(5, NA, 6)
v2 = c(4, 3, 7)
df1 = data.frame(v1,v2)
for (i in 1:ncol(df1)){
  print(colnames(df1)[i])
  print(sum(is.na(df1[,i])))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colSums` to count number of empty values in each column.

```
colSums(df1 == '')

# v1 v2 
# 1  0
```

If you have `NA` values instead of blank use `is.na` :

```
colSums(is.na(df1))
```